# popup message box in xamarin.form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What I am trying to do is similar to DisplayAlert, popup a display page that contains image, content and a small close button at top right. The display page shouldn't cover the whole phone but just around 80% of the phone UI, background remain as parent page.

I am trying to play around with PushModalAsync and PopModalAsync, however with no luck. The output is not what I expected.

Basically, I have a listview, whenever item is selected from screen it will call for popUpMethod:

```
 list.ItemSelected += MyMethod;
```

inside MyMethod i will call popUpPage

```
async void MyMethod(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e){
Content = await PopUpPage();
}
```

and this is my PopUpPage method

```
private async Task<StackLayout> PopUpPage()
{
     StackLayout objPopUp = new StackLayout() { HeightRequest = 100, WidthRequest= 100, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand};

     Label lblMessage = new Label();
     lblMessage.Text = "Welcome";

     objPopUp.Children.Add(lblMessage);

     return objPopUp;
}
```

I am trying to set the height and width inside my popup page. However, it is still covering the whole screen which is not what I want. let me know if any top up information is needed, thank you.

P/S : i designed it in xamarin.Form(portable)

Comment: You could perhaps (though this is a hack - a "nice" version would be better, like an alert dialog) use an AbsoluteLayout and simply render elements on top of your current page by manipulating the UI element hierarchy (adding elements to your AbsoluteLayout page).

Comment: Either create the custom pop up natively and activate it through the DependencyService or MessangingCenter. Otherwise Brandon Minnick's answer is the correct way to do it. You wouldn't want to set the content of the page to your pop up because that would remove everything else.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom pop-up to accomplish this in Xamarin.Forms

Here is a custom `ContentView` that I created. It uses a `BoxView` to give the appearance of fading the background, and uses a `Frame` to add a shadow to the pop-up.

I also use animations to make the custom pop-up appear as if it is springing off of the screen!

## Sample App

The code for this sample app is available on Github:

https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp

[image: Custom Pop-up In Xamarin.Forms]

## Code Snippet

```
public class WelcomeView : ContentView
{
    readonly BoxView _backgroundOverlayBoxView;
    readonly Frame _overlayFrame;
    readonly StackLayout _textAndButtonStack;

    readonly RelativeLayout _relativeLayout;

    public WelcomeView()
    {
        const string titleText = "Welcome";
        const string bodyText = "Enjoy InvestmentDataSampleApp";
        const string okButtonText = "Ok, thanks!";

        var whiteWith75Opacity = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
        _backgroundOverlayBoxView = new BoxView
        {
            BackgroundColor = whiteWith75Opacity
        };
        _backgroundOverlayBoxView.Opacity = 0;

        _overlayFrame = new Frame
        {
            HasShadow = true,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };
        _overlayFrame.Scale = 0;

        var titleLabel = new Label
        {
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            Text = titleText,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
        };

        var bodyLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = bodyText,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
        };

        var blackWith75PercentOpacity = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        var okButton = new Button
        {
            BackgroundColor = blackWith75PercentOpacity,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BorderWidth = 1,
            BorderColor = blackWith75PercentOpacity,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            Margin = new Thickness(5),
            Text = okButtonText
        };
        okButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => 
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await this.FadeTo(0);
                this.IsVisible = false;
                this.InputTransparent = true;
            });
        }

        _textAndButtonStack = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Spacing = 20,
            Children = {
                titleLabel,
                bodyLabel,
                okButton
            }
        };
        _textAndButtonStack.Scale = 0;

        _relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
        Func<RelativeLayout, double> gettextAndButtonStackHeight = (p) => _textAndButtonStack.Measure(_relativeLayout.Width, _relativeLayout.Height).Request.Height;
        Func<RelativeLayout, double> gettextAndButtonStackWidth = (p) => _textAndButtonStack.Measure(_relativeLayout.Width, _relativeLayout.Height).Request.Width;


        _relativeLayout.Children.Add(_backgroundOverlayBoxView,
            Constraint.Constant(-10),
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width + 20),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Height)
        );
        _relativeLayout.Children.Add(_overlayFrame,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - gettextAndButtonStackWidth(parent) / 2 - 20),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Height / 2 - gettextAndButtonStackHeight(parent) / 2 - 10),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => gettextAndButtonStackWidth(parent) + 30),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => gettextAndButtonStackHeight(parent) + 30)
        );

        _relativeLayout.Children.Add(_textAndButtonStack,
             Constraint.RelativeToView(_overlayFrame, (parent, view) => view.X + 15),
             Constraint.RelativeToView(_overlayFrame, (parent, view) => view.Y + 15)
        );

        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
        {
            _overlayFrame.IsVisible = false;
            _textAndButtonStack.BackgroundColor = whiteWith90Opacity;
        }

        Content = _relativeLayout;
    }

    public void DisplayView()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            var animationList = new List<Task>
            {
                _backgroundOverlayBoxView.FadeTo(1,AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewAnimationTime),
                _textAndButtonStack.ScaleTo(AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewMaxSize, AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewAnimationTime),
                _overlayFrame.ScaleTo(AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewMaxSize,AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewAnimationTime)
            };
            await Task.WhenAll(animationList);

            animationList = new List<Task>
            {
                _textAndButtonStack.ScaleTo(AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewNormalSize, AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewAnimationTime),
                _overlayFrame.ScaleTo(AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewNormalSize, AnimationConstants.WelcomeViewAnimationTime)
            };
            await Task.WhenAll(animationList);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PushModalAsync  will push page over your current page. Instead use same page add one frame in it. configure frame with whatever controls you want.
1. set frame Visibility to false and on ItemSelected make frame visible. OR
2. add frame dynamically on ItemSelected  (haven't tried 2nd approach.).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like as following.

```
private async Task<StackLayout> PopUpPage () { 
    StackLayout objPopUp = new StackLayout () {HeightRequest = 0, WidthRequest = 0, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, Padding = 10 }; 
    Label lblMessage = new Label (); 
    lblMessage.Text = "Welcome"; 
    objPopUp.Children.Add (lblMessage); 
    return objPopUp; 
}
```

Comment: Setting the HeightRequest and WidthRequest to 0 won't give the desired effect

Answer (score -1):

You may use the XLabs-PopUp-Control. 
With that control, you can show a PopUp from you page where you can define the size without problems. I use it on various pages.
[Link how to use it](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33587/how-to-use-a-listview-in-a-scrollview-with-xlabs-popup-control#latest)

[Link how to install and setup XLabs](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35991/how-to-install-setup-and-use-xlabs#latest)