# xamarin forms, popup window by tapping a word in a nlock of text inside a label

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I'd like to implement a glossary in a xamarin forms app , ie: if the user taps a word in a block of text inside a label, a windows is popped up with an explanation of the word.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please take the time to read the help files about how to ask a good question.  What you've posted isn't a question, just a set of requirements.

Comment: Here's a post about creating a custom pop up in Xamarin.Forms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739136/popup-message-box-in-xamarin-form/41368417#41368417