# Xamarin pop up with default close button in Xamarin form pcl

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

Can anyone suggest a best method to show pop up with close button by default in Xamarin forms with animations. To be more specific, if we are clicking on a card, it should come from the location of tap or click.

I have used xlabs for the same. Is there any other packages that I can use?

Could you share a sample code if possible?

Comment: On _Stack Overflow_, the phrases "please help me out" and "share a sample code" are usually understood to mean "please do my work for me". To avoid such a misunderstanding, it is ideal to show what research you have done so far, and what code you have tried. Could you edit your question to include that?

Comment: @halfer sorry buddy... I am new in stackoverflow and this is my first post. Sorry... :)

Comment: That guideline extends very well to all other sources of help on the internet. A key part of being a software engineer is to give it a genuine go yourself first. May I look forward to your doing so, and then editing your post afterwards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popup message box in xamarin.form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739136/popup-message-box-in-xamarin-form)